# Giving several unique ID´s to a MySql row and using php to show all rows with one special ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a system that manages a lot of articles and some articles are needed in more than one article series.

I am wondering how I can give one row in Mysql several unique ID´s and extracting them from the database with PHP.

It only reads the first ID and not the next.
I have tried seperating them with a comma, but if I write 10, 122.
Only 10 will be read as an ID and 122 will be ignored.

I am not very skilled with programming, but I am doing my best to learn it, Hope you can help me! :-)

The code I use to sort the articles in the system.

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$ro=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_articles 
                 WHERE fk_semikatagori_id=".$id." 
                 ORDER BY ABS(sortering) ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You need to normalize your tables, probably by creating an article_categories table with article id and category id columns.

Comment: You should normalize, as @user574632 says. But if you don't, you can use `FIND_IN_SET` to do what you want with a comma-delimited list.

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the one you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. Be careful, `$_REQUEST` values **never** go directly into a query.

Comment: You need to normalize your design, but if you don't you can of course dispense with using an RDBMS altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't fix the table design, use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
$ro=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_articles 
                 WHERE FIND_IN_SET($id, fk_semikatagori_id)
                 ORDER BY ABS(sortering) ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the help everyone, I used the FIND_IN_SET and regarding the deprecated issues and security issues.
They are planned to be fixed by a professional later on and the system will stay offline until then :-)

Answer (score 2):

Each article is unique, right? Keep it having a unique ID. What you should do is create an additional table, like @user574632 has suggested, where you don't have any unique fields but this will allow you to create your "categories" (or "series") and add each unique article to that table. You then search THAT table to obtain all the IDs of articles that are supposed to be in a series.

E.g.

`Articles
    ========
    ID   |    Title         |    Body
    1    |    My Article    |    This is my article
    2    |    StackExchange |    My article on Stack Exchange...`

`Categories
    ========
    SeriesID    |    ArticleID
    1           |    1
    1           |    2
    2           |    1`

You then query the categories table to obtain all the article IDs you require for your series...